# Zk how to reach included .zul page component by id?

Tags: include, zk

I can't reach component by id in the included .zul page. I have one main.zul with a controller and I need to get a component in included zul page through the java controller  class, but it returns null.

I know the included method creates new id space but is there any way to get this component?

**UPDATE**

Here is my code:

the main zul page

```
<?page title="DealerVizard.zul"?>

<?page id="main" ?>

<?taglib uri="http://www.zkoss.org/dsp/web/core" prefix="c"?>
<?init class="org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.AnnotateDataBinderInit" arg0="./Dealer" ?>
<zk>
    <style src="/resources/css/default.css" />
    <window id="Dealer" class="index" 
        apply="com.i2i.prm.controller.IndexController">


        <div class="content" width="100%">

            <tabbox id="tb" forward="onSelect=onSelect">
                <tabs id="tabs">
                    <tab id="info" label="INFO" />
                    <tab id="create" label="CREATE" />
                    <tab id="edit" label="EDIT" />
                    <tab id="test" label="TEST PANEL(LIST BOX)" />

                </tabs>
                <tabpanels>
                    <tabpanel id="DealerInfo">
                        <include id="DealerInfoContent"
                            src="View/Dealer/DealerInfo.zul" />
                    </tabpanel>
                    <tabpanel id="DealerCreate">
                        <include id="DealerCreateContent"
                            src="View/Dealer/DealerCreate.zul" />
                    </tabpanel>
                    <tabpanel id="DealerEdit">
                        <include id="DealerEditContent"
                            src="View/Dealer/DealerEdit.zul" />
                    </tabpanel>

                    <tabpanel id="PagingListBox">
                        <include  id="PagingListBoxContent"  // Included here
                            src="View/TEST/PagingListBox.zul" />
                    </tabpanel>
                </tabpanels>
            </tabbox>
        </div>
    </window>

</zk>
```

PagingListBox.zul (Included page)

```
<?page id="list" ?>

<zk>

    <grid width="100%">

        <columns>
            <column label="" />

        </columns>
        <rows>
            <row>
                <listbox id="listModel" width="100%" height="100%"
                    visible="true" span="true" pagingPosition="top" rows="20"
                    selectedItem="@{DealerController.selected}"
                    model="@{DealerController.userList}"
                    forward="onSelect=//main/Dealer.onSelect">
                    <auxhead>
                        <auxheader colspan="1">
                            <textbox
                                value="@{DealerController.searchUser.name}" maxlength="9"
                                id="searchCO_ID" forward="onChanging=//main/Dealer.onSearch"
                                width="100%">
                            </textbox>
                        </auxheader>
                        <auxheader colspan="1">
                            <textbox
                                value="@{DealerController.searchUser.surname}" maxlength="21"
                                id="searchMSISDN" forward="onChanging=//main/Dealer.onSearch"
                                width="100%">
                            </textbox>
                        </auxheader>
                        <auxheader colspan="1">

                        </auxheader>

                    </auxhead>

                    <listhead>
                        <listheader label="Name"
                            sort="auto(UPPER(name))" />

                        <listheader label="Surname"
                            sort="auto(UPPER(surname))" />


                        <listheader label="Delete ?" />
                    </listhead>


                    <listitem self="@{each=USERLIST}">

                        <listcell>
                            <label value="@{USERLIST.user.name}" />
                            <textbox
                                value="@{DealerController.tmpUser.name}" visible="false" />
                        </listcell>
                        <listcell>
                            <label value="@{USERLIST.user.surname}" />
                            <textbox
                                value="@{DealerController.tmpUser.surname}" visible="false" />
                        </listcell>

                        <listcell>
                            <button label="Update"
                                forward="onClick=//main/Dealer.onUpdate" visible="false" />
                            <button image="icons/edit-delete.png"
                                label="Delete" forward="onClick=//main/Dealer.onDelete"
                                width="100%" disabled="true" />
                            <button label="Save"
                                forward="onClick=//main/Dealer.onSave" visible="false" />
                            <button label="Cancel"
                                forward="onClick=//main/Dealer.onCancel" visible="false" />
                        </listcell>
                    </listitem>
                </listbox>
                <paging id="pagingData" pageSize="20" />
            </row>

        </rows>
    </grid>
</zk>
```

IndexCOntroller.java

```
public class IndexController extends  GenericForwardComposer  {

    private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>() ;
    AnnotateDataBinder binder;
    Tabbox tb;
    Window Dealer;
    private int pageCount=0;

    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
        comp.setVariable(comp.getId() + "Controller", this, true);
        binder = (AnnotateDataBinder) Dealer.getVariable("binder", true);


    System.out.println(Path.getComponent("//list/listModel"));
    }


    public IndexController() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally I wouldn't recommend using `Path.getComponent()` way to access other components as your application code becomes tightly coupled with your component structure in your view page.
In your case you simplest way is to use [`AbstractComponent#getFellow(String compId)`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/AbstractComponent.html#getFellow%28java.lang.String%29) method so for eg.

```
Include inc = (Include) Dealer.getFellow("PagingListBoxContent");
Listbox listModel = (Listbox) inc.getFellow("listModel");
System.out.println(listModel);
```

So in future even if you insert any other component in your ZUML page before your listbox your code will still work.

**UPDATE**: BTW there was an interesting [blogpost](http://blog.zkoss.org/index.php/2011/06/21/zk-demythtified-myth-i/) on this very topic on ZK blog

Comment: I suggest to replace "recently" with "in 2011" (now I cannot edit that since the edit queue is full)

Answer (score 1):

if your include have id, you can use dollar sign to get the inner components

```
  <zk>
  <include id="inc" src="test.zul />

  </zk>
```

test.zul

```
    <zk>
    <label id="lab1" value="test1" />
    </zk>
```

you can use "inc$lab1" get the label in test.zul

Answer (score 0):

You can access any component in any other id space using zscript or java. if it is on the same page, but different window then (component B in window A):

```
Path.getComponent("/A/B");
```

if it is on a different page then (component B in window A on page P):

```
Path.getComponent("//P/A/B");
```

You can find documentation here: http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/UI%20Composing/ID%20Space

Comment: I trıed it but it works only for view page that belogns to controller class. using   
 System.out.println(Path.getComponent("//includedPageID/listboxID"));  returns null. Included page have no window. Only div tags and listbox.

Comment: @Meko: Your code looks OK to me, I made a little mock-up to test it (with ZK 3.6.4). //list/listModel should resolve the listbox in the included ZUL. Is it possible you've used the page id "list" in multiple ZUL files, so it is not unique?

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your IndexController.java:

```
...
   private Include DealerInfoContent;
...
```

this way you can access the included component within the parent composer.

(I would suggest to use camelCase ids for it, though).