# zk can't access method in included .zul

Tags: methods, include, zk

When I try the below code (as is suggested here by Ryan Wu for [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661675/zk-how-to-reach-included-zul-page-component-by-id)):

```
<?page title="Auto Generated index.zul"?>
<window title="Hello World 2!!" border="none" width="600px">    
    <include id="inc" src="/zk/wind.zul" mode="instant" />
    <button label="do it" onClick="inc$wind.doModal()" />
</window>
```

After pressing the button I am getting this error:

```
inc$wind.doModal();'' : Attempt to resolve method: doModal() on undefined variable or class name
```

The file wind.zul looks as

```
<?page title="new page title" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<zk>
<window id="wind" title="new page title" border="normal" visible="false" width="300px">
New Content Here!
</window>
</zk>
```

Can someone let me know what is wrong? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

According to http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/UI%20Composing/ID%20Space
I need:
1. use '**Path**' 
2. add some ID for main window (f.i. **id=**"w0")
and write in ***index.zul*** something similar ( file ***wind.zul*** not changed)

```
<?page title="Auto Generated index.zul"?>
<window id="w0" title="Hello World 2!!" border="none" width="600px">    
    <include id="inc" src="/zk/wind.zul" mode="instant" />
    <button label="do it" onClick='Path.getComponent("/w0/inc/wind").doModal()' />
</window>
```

Thanks for me own :))